# Python error unhashable type: 'list' with pandas iloc

Tags: python, pandas, list, if-statement

I am still learning Python.  I am trying to check if the peak value of any of the average temperatures is satisfied using the if statement below but I am getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.  Can someone help clarify the issue and correct it?

Thank you!

```
df['T1avg'] = df['T1'].rolling(11, center=True).mean().shift(50)
df['T2avg'] = df['T2'].rolling(11, center=True).mean().shift(50)
averages = ['T1avg','T2avg']

pctl = np.nanpercentile(df, 1, axis=0)  # calculation of 1% percentile
peak = df.iloc[-1] < pctl

for i in range(1, len(df)):
if (peak.loc(axis=0)[i, averages]).any():
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the *full* error message, every line of it.  I can't tell where the error would be coming from.

Comment: remove (axis=0)

Comment: That's the full error message I am getting from Jupyter.  When (axis=0) is removed, I get IndexingError: Too many indexers.